# How should I structure this database?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a website that will allow people to make lists, but I'm not sure on the best way to store these lists. Should I make a new table for each user, or is that a bad idea? There will be a few columns to each list.

Thanks in advance

Edit: It will be one list per user, although if it's pretty much the same, I may make it multiple lists to give more options in future. Each list will contain the item, a priority, and possibly another column or two. Users will be able to add, edit, and delete items from their list, and make it private or public.

Comment: whatever you do, don't make a seperate list table for each user. :) If you create a common, re-usable database structure, your life will be happier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Red Filter noted, you should split your info across multiple tables. Your structure depends on what you wish to store in the list, and how users should interact with the lists.. Should one user get to see other users lists? Have multiple lists?

This structure for example lets users have multiple lists, and each list have multiple items:

```
list
  list_id
  list_name
  creator (user_id)

list_items
  list_id
  item

user_list
  user_id
  list_id
```

Comment: And you can use foreign keys for referential integrity.

Comment: Yes, always a good idea. Note that you must use InnoDB if you wish to use foreign keys. MyISAM doesn't support this.

Comment: How do I then use a foreign key? I know how to add one, but how does it help me, compared to it being a regular column and just querying it to get the user id?

Comment: @SGWebsNow: The online MySQL reference is also very good and have comments at the bottom of every page.

Comment: I've always found it messy and confusing. Most of the time, it's easier looking at other sites.

Comment: Hmm.. I always look at the reference site and find it quite clear. Of course, it's mostly a reference and not everything are explained in great detail.

Comment: That's probably why. I find the PHP documentation great, but I am fairly proficient in that area anyway. MySQL on the other hand is still quite a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a bad idea to create a new table for each user. Instead, add a `UserID` column to your `List` table.

Then you can get a given user's lists like this:

```
select ListID, Name
from List
where UserID = 42 --example UserID
```

If the lists have the same schema, then you can create a a single `ListValues` table with a `ListID` column that is an `FK` to the `List` table, with the columns you require. If each user can create their own columns, then you may want to implement an [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) model.

Answer (score 1):

Its bad idea your list table should something  like following.

```
id list user_id
```